# How to animate UIImage like Marque Tag in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uilabel

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to animate image same as marque tag. I am animating UILabel text and for that my code is like this

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        scrolllbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,scrolllbl.bounds.size.width, 1800)];
        NSString *theText = @"A long string";
        CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50);
        scrolllbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [scrolllbl setNumberOfLines:0];
        CGFloat fontSize = 30;
        while (fontSize > 0.0)
        {
            CGSize size = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            if (size.height <= labelRect.size.height) break;

            fontSize -= 1.0;
        }

        //set font size
        scrolllbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:fontSize];
    }
    else
    {
        scrolllbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,scrolllbl.bounds.size.width, 800)];
      //  scrolllbl.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    //lbl2.text=result1;
    NSLog(@"Result Array =%@",shortnamearray);
    CGFloat y = 10;

    NSMutableArray* animals = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSUInteger maxCount = headarray.count > shortnamearray.count ? headarray.count : shortnamearray.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i ++) {
        if ([headarray objectAtIndex:i]) {
            [animals addObject:[headarray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        if ([shortnamearray objectAtIndex:i]) {
            [animals addObject:[shortnamearray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Array is =%@",animals);


    for(int i=0;i<[shortnamearray count] && i<[headarray count];i++){
        // y+=20;
        y+=10;
        NSString *newArray =[animals objectAtIndex:i];
        newArray=[animals componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        NSString *NewString;

        [scrolllbl setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
         scrolllbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        //[scrolllbl setText:NewString];
        NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body>";
        NSString *htmlString2=@"</body></html>";
        NewString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",htmlString,newArray,htmlString2];

        NSLog(@"New String =%@",NewString);

        NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[NewString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

        scrolllbl.attributedText = attrStr;
        NSString *theText = @"A long string";
        CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 50);
        scrolllbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [scrolllbl setNumberOfLines:0];
        CGFloat fontSize = 15;
        while (fontSize > 0.0)
        {
            CGSize size = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(labelRect.size.width, 10000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

            if (size.height <= labelRect.size.height) break;

            fontSize -= 1.0;
        }

        //set font size
        scrolllbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:fontSize];
    }


    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timer)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

    //[_scrollView scrollRectToVisible:NSMakeRange(0,0,0.0) animated:YES];
    [newsscroll addSubview:scrolllbl];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(newsscroll.frame.size.width+[shortnamearray count], scrolllbl.frame.size.height);
```

This is how I am doing for UILabel.Please give me suggestion how to do for UIImage.My main problem is that image can be multiple accourding to data comming from web service.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use UICollectionView for your requirement of multiple i,age with marque effect.

Comment: Please try this https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel

Comment: @CodeChanger How can I add marque effect in that?

Answer (score 1):

You can Animate image Simple code using `animateWithDuration` :

in `viewDidLoad` call `addAllImages` :

```
-(void)addAllImages
{
    scr=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 0, 320, 150)];
    float xPosition=5;
    for (int i =0; i<=10; i++) {
        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 0, 150, 150)];
        img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"];
        [scr addSubview:img];
        xPosition+=150+5;
    }
    scr.frame=CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 0, xPosition, 150);
}
```

call `animateImage` method for when you animate Image :

```
   -(void)animateImage
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^
     {
         scr.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, scr.frame.size.width, scr.frame.size.height);
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         scr.frame=CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,0, scr.frame.size.width, scr.frame.size.height);
         [self animateImage];
     }];

}
```

Comment: But this animate only one image.

Comment: if you have multiple image than First add all images in scrollview and than you can animate scrollview

Comment: Now check it and replay me if any Problem

Comment: hello @Muju if its Work please Right the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please view [this link](https://github.com/Kalvar/ios-KRMarqueeScrollView) at will take images array and time interval for move may be its helpful to you.and also its very easy to use